# How Can I send an email to the author of a Site Page when a comment is Made

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Communications site which has site pages with comments enabled.  How can I send an email to a site page's author when a comment is received on that page ?

I can get my hands on the comments on a site page using a REST Call so -> [working with page comments](http://www.vrdmn.com/2017/07/working-with-page-comments-rest-api-in.html)  by Vardhaman Deshpande, but how do I trigger an email [either using or not using Flow] when a comment is added to a site page ?

Regards

Nigel

Answer (score 0):

The API you mentioned is used to get/post comments for page in communication site, which can't trigger any actions.

You can add JS code on the page, monitor the page and send email if any comment is added.

What can do in "Modern" site:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites